# What's the best practice to send a message

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

**The objective:**

Call an action and show a message for display the result "success/error",

**The Problem:**

Actually, I know how to do this using JQuery, but I don't know if that's the best way,

**??** I would like to know if it could be better doing all of these from server side, I mean call only an ActionLink and then execute a javascript or return a message from server.

**The Code:**
MVC3 C#

View:

```
    $('#btnValidate')
        .click(function(e) {
         $.ajax({
            url: "/Valoration/ValidateHvm" ,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                           if(data.success){
                                 alert('success');
                           }else{ 
                                 alert('error');
                      },
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });

     });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ValidateHvm()
    {
        var result = HvmService.ValidateProject;
        return Json(new { success = result});
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this solution, it seems the best way to me, you can use ModelState.AddModelError() if you wish but your actionresult will need to redisplay the view with the model

Comment: I don't know if have sens talk about User expirence on that question... I'm sure you're borred at home without nothing better to do posting Shit on stackoverflow. Waste your time doing interesting things. I asked that question because as you can see here:     http://chalaki.com/two-ways-to-render-mvc3-partial-views-client-side-javascript-or-server-side-html-helper/713/ we have other ways of do that, and I would like to know what's more recommended

Comment: The way you are using Ajax would be the better way to display success/errors to the user.  Mostly due that you do not have to reload the entire View.  You can just return whatever error message and move on.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your implementation, it seems the best way to me, but another way is you can use ModelState.AddModelError() if you wish but your actionresult will need to redisplay the view with the model

So you post will accept the model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateHvm(ValidateModel model)
{
    var result = HvmService.ValidateProject(model);

    if(result == false){ //or whatever

       ModelState.AddModelError("","Error");

    }


        return View("MyView", model)
}
```